How to execute SQL on R workbench via a starburst connector?
What: Need to connect fetch data from a db using RStudio workbench and Trino.
Issue: Always errors out. Connection to presto host using the same method works fine. Trino driver version is 443 (which is latest at the time of writing)
Constraints: Has to be a JDBC connection. This is an enterprise environment so have limited ability to test or influence changes to RStudio, however some package install etc can be influenced.
What do I need: Guidance on what is wrong with my code? If the issue is not my code, then what needs to change in RStudio workbench to make it work.
Code:
dyn.load(
  '/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402.b06-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so'
)

library(DBI)
library(RJDBC)

user <<- Sys.info()[['user']]
pwd <- rstudioapi::askForPassword(prompt = "Enter SSO Password")

home <- paste0("/mnt/efs/users/",user)
cert_path <- "/connections/starburst/"
certificate <- "SHA2-CA-Bundle.cer"
certificate2 <- "sep.jks"
jar_files = c(list.files(paste0(home,cert_path),
                         pattern="jar$",
                         full.names=T)
)

# driver_class <- "io.trino.jdbc.NonRegisteringTrinoDriver"
driver_class <- "io.trino.jdbc.TrinoDriver"

drv <- RJDBC::JDBC(driverClass = driver_class,
                   classPath = jar_files)
host <- 
  "jdbc:trino://myhost.com:111/hive"

server <-
  paste0(
    host,
    "?user=", user,
    "&password=", pwd,
    # "&SSL=true",
    "&SSLVerification=CA",
    # "&SSLTrustStorePath=", home, cert_path, certificate,
    "&SSLKeyStorePath=",home, cert_path, certificate2
  )

server

conn <<- DBI::dbConnect(drv, server)

query_input <- "SELECT count(*) FROM some.table"

output <- dbGetQuery(conn, query_input)

View(output)

dbDisconnect(conn)


Error:
Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set",  : 
  Unable to retrieve JDBC result set
  JDBC ERROR: Error executing query: Error fetching next (attempts: 4, duration: 2.01m)
  Statement: SELECT count(*) FROM some.table

